# Fermat's Little theorem (Num Theory)

Tags: number-theory

How can I compute $31^{1209}\equiv \mod (101)$ using Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: What does Fermat's Little Theorem say?  (*I know, of course, but am asking if* **you** *know*).  Try to include some work of your own in your question posts, else it is liable to be closed due to lack of effort shown and missing context/details.

Comment: Fermat's Little theorem states that if a^p is congruent to a (mod p) then there exists a d such that a^(d) -1 is congruent to 0 (mod p) and a^(p-1)-1 is congruent to 0 (mod p)

Comment: It doesn't state **if** $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$, that is the result, not the hypothesis.

Comment: If p is a prime number and a is natural number is the hypothesis.

Comment: Yes.  You used the word "**if**" in your original comment in an incorrect way.  Grammar is incredibly important in mathematics, regardless what elementary school would have you believe.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $31^{1209} = 31^{1200}\cdot 31^{9}=(31^{100})^{12}\cdot 31^9$

What does Fermat's Little theorem say about $31^{100}\pmod{101}$?

Comment: Ok so, 31^(100)-1 is congruent to 0 (mod 101) based on the theorem right?

Comment: @agriffin it is easier to use it as $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ for any integer $a$ and prime $p$ where $\gcd(a,p)=1$.  Instead of dealing with zeroes, it is easier to deal with ones.

Comment: Okay thank you. How can I simplify the 31^9 part?